# Don't include test definition files in Typescript IntelliSense and output

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm working on an app in Angular.js. I'm having an issue where `@types/angular-mocks` definitions are applied for all files under `src/**`. I'd like for the definition file for `angular-mocks` to only apply to files that match `src/**/*.spec.ts`.

- Prevent mock methods from showing in real controllers
- Prevent mock library from being referenced in `d.ts` output files

The code below shows my issue with a typical controller and the `d.ts` output:

**my-controller.ts**

```
import * as ng from 'angular';

export class MyController {
  constructor(public $timeout: ng.ITimeoutService) {}

  method() {
    // I don't want this method to be shown
    this.$timeout.flush();
  }
}
```

**my-controller.d.ts**

```
/// <reference types="angular" />
/// <reference types="angular-mocks" />
// I want to prevent the above reference from being added
import * as ng from 'angular';
export declare class MyController {
    $timeout: ng.ITimeoutService;
    constructor($timeout: ng.ITimeoutService);
    method(): void;
}
```

Just in case it's relevant, here is the `tsconfig.json` settings:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "newLine": "LF",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

I haven't found a good way to accomplish this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what if you exclude: ['*.d.ts'] in your tsconfig?

Comment: I don't want to exclude then all. E.g. I want `@types/angular` to load in my controller, but I don't want `@types/angular-mocks`. I only want to exclude one library in `@types`, and that only for files not ending in `*.spec.ts`.